# What are the process and notice periods for no fault evictions in FL, and does it matter whether one is renting only a room in the landlords house?

Tags: landlord, florida

Suppose Alice rents a room from Bob in Bob's house where he lives, and they sign a tenancy contract.

Suppose after some time, Bob wants Alice out. How can he go about achieving this, and how much warning must he give her in the state of Florida?

Comment: How long is the tenancy agreement for? Is it month-to-month, annual, or for some other term?

Comment: Alice isn’t a tenant, she’s a lodger. Different laws apply.

Comment: Not sure how long the tenancy is for, but interested in all of those cases.

Comment: Do lodgers exist in the USA?

Comment: https://www.justanswer.com/real-estate-law/8tloc-lodger-laws-florida.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's not completely clear to me if Alice's rights are restricted due to her only renting a room in the landlords home, her notice period following the end of her fixed term depends on how frequently she pays her rent:

For a tenant with rent due weekly she must be given 7 days notice to quit for the tenancy to be terminated. For one with rent due monthly they must receive 15 days. Quarterly, 30 days; yearly, 60 days.